# Self Destructing email after being viewed in PHP

Tags: php, html

is there a way of creating a one-time self destructing email in PHP? I am working on a project and the client wants to send price quotations via email. However, the email should self destruct after a user sees it once

Comment: I see loads of cyber hacks and wars with this ;). I like your style

Comment: The only way to be sure that it's self-destructed is to take out the entire neighbourhood with a high-yield nuclear strike

Comment: In short: no. Even if you sent a link to some self-destructing page… it's always possible to safe it/take a screenshot/photocopy it.

Comment: Mission: impossible

Comment: @Mark And that's where the HTML5 geolocation API comes in handy…

Comment: oh okay. Good to know

Comment: The more I reread this the more my eyes are spinning in their sockets… this is such an inane request at so many levels… This is not a problem to be solved with technology. If you want to set a "timeout" on an offer, write that next to the offer ("Only valid until X"). If you want people to forget what you told them, do a lobotomy. If you want to keep something absolutely secret, **don't put it in writing.**

Comment: There's also potential legal repercussions... if your client is quoting prices, but then destroying the quotes, it has a lot of potential for fraud; and if there is any legal dispute over the price, then it's destroying evidence in the eyes of the law

Answer (score -2):

> What you could do is write a file when the page is seen. If the file
>   exists, return a 404 error, else, write the file & display the email.
>   But what might happen is the mail destructing itself before getting to
>   your recipient mail box : any crawler would trigger the destruction.

Wouldn't that work ?

HTML page containing a img with source pointing towards a PHP script.
When the page is seen, write a file. If the file exists, return a blank image, else, write the file & display the price in form of an image.

Comment: Please entertain me on how you would destroy the mail from my inbox